# How to load ui-router states into the content of ui-bootstrap tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm learning angular, and have been trying to dynamically load a HTML file fragment into the content pane of a tab.

In [this linked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ivdnhaCO58vAd0fuZa60?p=preview) I have created an angular module to configure the states

```
var app = angular.module('Plunker', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])

    app.config([
        '$stateProvider',
        '$urlRouterProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

            $stateProvider        
                .state("tab1", { url: "/tab1", templateUrl: "tab1.html" })
                .state("tab2", { url: "/tab2", templateUrl: "tab2.html" })
                .state("tab3", { url: "/tab3", templateUrl: "tab3.html" });
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        }]);

    app.controller("tabsController", function ($rootScope, $scope, $state) {

        $scope.tabs = [
            { title: "My Tab 1", route: "tab1", active: true },
            { title: "My Tab 2", route: "tab2", active: false },
            { title: "My Tab 3", route: "tab3", active: false },
        ];

        $scope.go = function (route) {
            $state.go(route);
        };

        $scope.active = function (route) {
            return $state.is(route);
        };

        $scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function () {
            $scope.tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
                tab.active = $scope.active(tab.route);
            });
        });
    });
```

and in the index.html body assign the ui-view a name to associate it with the state/route

```
<body ng-app="Plunker">
   <div ng-controller="tabsController">
        <uib-tabset>
            <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">

                <div ui-view="{{tab.route}}"></div>

            </uib-tab>
        </uib-tabset>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Each tab should have content coming from the respective html file fragment tab1.html, tab2.html or tab1.html.  But I cant get it to work.  Any help making this work would be much appreciated.

Comment: if you want a tab per route, you don't need `<uib-tabset>` just use tabs css and regular links

Comment: @charlietfl thanks i'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to have one partial for each tab. For that, the *named views* feature of ui-router can help you. You won't change state, but having the content on dedicated views allows you to keep the parent template light and nicely organize your code. Moreover you could reuse the tab templates elsewhere.

***State definition where the tabset component resides:***

```
$stateProvider
    .state('example', {
        url: '/example',
        views: {
            "tab1": { templateUrl: "tab1.html" },
            "tab2": { templateUrl: "tab2.html" },
            "tab3": { templateUrl: "tab3.html" },
    }
```

***Tabset definition:***

```
<uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" ...>
        <div ui-view="{{tab.route}}"></div>  <!-- ex: <div ui-view="tab1"></div> -->
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

See [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G5mg8HbXYOjdsWJnKkVT?p=preview)

Comment: This doesn't directly apply to what I'm working on, but I really like your code here.  Thanks!

Comment: How can I achieve this if I have a separated navigation partial template and inside each item in the menu there is a ui-sref item with the state definition, I want the controller to add a new tab item and push all content comming from the templateUrl configure in the state provider.
Currently each time I click an item it loads the content inside the ui-view item, so instead of adding a new tab it only adds the content in the first tab, it never creates a new tab